# JSON formatting error which is hard to understand

Tags: json, mqtt, paho, aws-iot

I am sending the following valid JSON as a message via MQTT to a device :

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "known": true,
      "local": false,
      "eep": "MSC_V3_PRESSAC_20",
      "id": "01:96:23:83",
      "O_nominalVoltage": 120
    }
  ],
  "uuid": "821ca781-dd98-4531-8391-19d4e4da2c96"
}
```

but I receive the following error back :

```
"Handling command: org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 62 of {devices:[{known:true,local:false,eep:MSC_V3_PRESSAC_20,id:01:96:23:83,O_nominalVoltage:120}],uuid:821ca781-dd98-4531-8391-19d4e4da2c96}"
```

}

Can anyone see anything wrong with this? I don't understand why there is a problem with character 62.

For more information, I am sending the message via the *mosquitto_pub* command when publishing to an MQTT topic on a remote device.

My device is running Java code which uses the Java Paho libraries. I am using the AWS IoT MQTT broker.

Comment: This is valid JSON, but it seems to be complaining about the ":" within the id value .. and looks as if it stripped all the quotes?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand it. Strange

Comment: How are you sending the JSON, maybe you need to quote the quotes?

Comment: Seconding what @Ossip said. If you're using mosquito_pub and just passing the JSON on the command line, the shell will interpret the quotes. Try putting it in a file and use the -f option to have mosquitto_pub get its payload from the file.

Comment: @JohnRomkeyThanks for the suggestion. I will try that and let you know

Comment: The double-quotes are not optional.

Comment: @GambitSupport what do you mean?